# Azure Function apps - cannot retrieve from Dead Letter Queue (DLQ)

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-node-sdk

I am following the **nodejs** examples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/packages/%40azure/servicebus/data-plane/examples/javascript/advancedFeatures/processMessageFromDLQ.js) to retrieve messages sent to the dead letter queue. I was pushing dead letters to the Q in this manner:

```js
await brokeredMessage.deadLetter({
      deadletterReason: 'bad',
      deadLetterErrorDescription: 'too bad, so sad.',
    });
```

I do see the dead letter count is **2** in Azure. Whether these arrived as a result of my deadletter code above or whether some other mishap caused messages to be dead-lettered, I have 2 in the DLQ. However **I can't retrieve them** with:

```js
  const client = ns.createQueueClient(queueName);
  const receiver = client.getReceiver();
  const sender = client.getSender();
  const messages = await receiver.receiveBatch(100);

  if (messages.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i += 1) { ... }
  } else {
    // I ALWAYS GET HERE. 
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? There are no errors. Why can't I read the DLQ and retrieve the 2 items there? Does the queue name change like it does for poison messages? I am using the same queuename while sending, deadlettering and trying to read the DLQ.

Comment: What is the variable ns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you need to append `/$DeadLetterQueue` to your queue name. So `const deadLetterQueueName = queueName + "/$DeadLetterQueue";`

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/4660) here on the azure-sdk-for-node repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
const client = ns.CreateQueueClient(QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(queueName));
```

since all your messages are in your dead-letter queue,you can receive the messages from the dead-letter path by creating a message receiver for the dead-letter end of the queue